# How to get comments for Youtube video via API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an abstract question: How can I get **comments** (Not count of comments!) from Youtube via API fast? I mean in API side - I have a powerful server and fine code. But via API it's really painful long process.

I see only one way. There are steps:

1. Make API request for get first page of comments;
2. Save comments from step 1 and get **nextPageToken** from response;
3. Make API request with **pageToken** option from step 2;
4. So... Loop steps 2 and 3 while have a **nextPageToken** in response.

If we have 10-20-50 pages of comments it's painful... But if we have 1k+ pages of comments it's a HELL! And we have a limit for API requests... So for 2-3 popular videos we can spend the limit.

It looks like I can't find something :) It can't be so hard... Isn't it?

How do you get a comments from Youtube?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the max comment retrieval limit is 100 each time right? So i guess you will have to go that way anyway. Have you tried any non-API solution? I found  [this](https://github.com/egbertbouman/youtube-comment-downloader) but not sure if working better (or at all)?

Comment: Yes, only 100 per page. 
Hm, I've tried right now download via provided non-API script. Downloaded 6729 comments in 4 minutes. Actually I think it could be the same speed but less reliability and unstable because of possible frontend modifications and specification. But it works, thank you!

Anyway, I think youtube has some API tools for fast get the comments... Or some life hacks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [CommentThreads.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) to get all the comments in a certain video. The required parameters you need to provide are `part`, `videoId` and `fields`.

And to test this, go to [Youtube API explorer Commenthreads.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.commentThreads.list?part=snippet&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=1&) and fill in the parameter for `videoId` (added the others for you). Then, click Authorize and Execute. All the comments of your video will be listed under `textOriginal`.

It's now up to you to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Yes, I do it like you said by default :) But it's really slowest way for high load because of limit max 100 results per page.